# Facebook pixel and multiple conversion tracking

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, e-commerce, prestashop

it is possible to implement multiple conversion tracking codes on one page? Or it will be count conversion to all tracking codes ? My tracking codes are facebook pixels and heureka.cz ( shop agregator in our country )

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, if you paste the conversion pixels into a page, they will fire when someone visits from Facebook UNLESS you specify to only fire on an event.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/conversion-pixel-code-migration#in-page-events

If you attach your pixels to different events, then they will only fire when those events are activated.